# Read and Write a single column in SQLite android

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, android-cursor

I want to read a single text column from my database and afterwards update it.
I created two methods below:

```
public boolean editNote(Lesson lesson) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(LessonsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_NOTE, lesson.getNote());
    String where = LessonsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + lesson.getId();
    int result = database.update(LessonsDBOpenHelper.TABLE_LESSONS, values, where, null);
    return (result == 1);

}
```

and

```
public String readNote(Lesson lesson) {

        String query = "SELECT * FROM lessons " +
                "WHERE lessonId =" +lesson.getId();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        String returnString = "";   // default value if nothing is found

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            returnString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LessonsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_NOTE));
        }
        cursor.close();
        return returnString;
        }
```

and then I call editNote() and readNote() methods from another activity like this:

```
public class Note extends Activity {

    private static final String LOGTAG = "MYAPP";
    Lesson lesson;
    LessonsDataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_note);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        lesson = b.getParcelable(".model.Lesson");

        Button noteSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.note_save);
        Button noteClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.note_clear);
        final TextView noteText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteText);

        String dbNote = datasource.readNote(lesson);
        noteText.setText(dbNote);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Note loaded from DB is "+dbNote);


        noteClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                noteText.setText("");
                lesson.setNote("");
                datasource.editNote(lesson);
            }
        });

        noteSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String note = noteText.getText().toString();
                lesson.setNote(note);
                datasource.editNote(lesson);
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "Note text changed to "+note);

                String dbNote = datasource.readNote(lesson);
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "Note text in DB is "+dbNote);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

But my app crashes when it gets to readNote or editNote methods.
What am I doing wrong?

I just want to read and then update a text filed in my database.

**Edit:**
Here is the LogCat:

```
01-30 02:47:29.809: D/AndroidRuntime(30850): Shutting down VM
01-30 02:47:29.809: W/dalvikvm(30850): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41744ba8)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850): Process: com.me.linux, PID: 30850
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.linux/com.me.linux.Note}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at com.me.linux.Note.onCreate(Note.java:31)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-30 02:47:29.809: E/AndroidRuntime(30850):    ... 11 more
01-30 02:59:51.589: I/MYAPP(31030): Database closed
```

**Edit 2:**
Here is the code of putExtra of the intent that starts this activity:

```
case R.id.action_edit_note:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Note.class);

            intent.putExtra(".model.Lesson", lesson);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1002);
            break;
```

Comment: crashes? Where's the logcat?

Comment: I added the LogCat from where the problem begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-open the database in the `readNote()` method so you can create the query.

Comment: @KianTamar Before you assign the value to the TextView check if it's *not* null. If not then you can `noteText.setText(dbNote);` else issue an error or whatever you want to do in such a case.

Comment: I tried your code, my app crashed again. I also manually changed the values in the database so it wouldn't be NULL. And my app crashed again

Comment: @KianTamar add `Log.i(LOGTAG, "dbNote= " +dbNote);` after `String dbNote = datasource.readNote(lesson);` so we can be sure that dbNote is not null. Then if it crashes check in logcat the number of the line that gives NPE and which line is that.

Comment: Two NPE. the first one is like logCat above in the 6th line

Comment: it should be something like this: `at com.me.linux.Note.onCreate(Note.java:31)`  Check the number and reply with that line from your class

Comment: The problem is even when I comment out the code that assigns the possible NULL value to the textView, My app crashes when it reaches to readNote(lesson);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46390/discussion-between-kian-tamar-and-mt0s)